# Memory Heap Size Keeps Increasing When Opening And Closing Activity

Tags: android, heap-memory

I launch activity B from A. Then i destroy B Activity. I then launch activity B from A again and so on. When i do this my heap size keeps increasing by about .5 MB every time.  I use android profiler and after when activity B is killed i force a garbage collection from android profiler. The problem is that the heap size after the GB is not decreasing. Also my code is the above, is a generic code from android studio. If there is a problem how can i see it through Heap Dump? Its shows many allocations and i dont understand it.

**MainActivity**

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            startActivity(newIntent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class));
        }
    });
}
```

**MainActivity2**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
}
```

**Check Logheap:**

```
 Log.d("tag", "debug. =================================");
                Log.d("tag", "debug.heap native: allocated " + df.format(allocated) + "MB of " + df.format(available) + "MB (" + df.format(free) + "MB free)");
                Log.d("tag", "debug.memory: allocated: " + df.format(new Double(Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() / 1048576.0)) + "MB of " + df.format(new Double(Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1048576.0)) + "MB (" + df.format(new Double(Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory() / 1048576.0)) + "MB free)");
```

Comment: @UmangBurman Nope.Irrelevant

Answer (score 1):

Dump your memory info,and ckeck instance count of your MainActivity2 after you finish it several times if count more than 0 and equals times which you start it then it means there is a memeory leak issue,or the count is zero then ignore it.

reedit:
add a picture,number of column Allocations is instance count,find your activity and check it[image: dumpinfo]

Comment: In dump info, where can i see the instance of activity?

Comment: I add a picture which should show you where to find it,please check it.

Comment: Okay thanks i will check it. Will it say activity on the left column?

Comment: Yes,buy the way ,I suggest that you can choose arrange by package,that will help you find your activity more quickly.